# How can I start a pod in privileged mode from a manifest?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to start a pod in privileged mode using the following manifest but it doesn't work for me.

```html
                     
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ftp
spec:
  privileged: true
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: ftp
    image: 84d3f7ba5876/ftp-run
```

Answer (score 1):

**`privileged: true`** needs to be in **`securityContext`** in the spec section of the pod template.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ftp
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: ftp
    image: 84d3f7ba5876/ftp-run
    securityContext:
            privileged: true
```

You can refer to this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context) for detailed information for privileged mode